# Select MAX StatusID

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have tables like this:

Status

```
StatusID | Status |
-------------------
1        | Good   |
2        | Nice   |
3        | Bad    |
```

Course

```
CourseID | Course |
-------------------
1        | Math   |
2        | Science|
3        | Art    |
```

Process

```
StudentID| CourseID | Status ID|
--------------------------------
1        | 1        | 1
1        | 2        | 1
1        | 2        | 2
2        | 1        | 3
2        | 1        | 1
```

i want result is this

```
StudentID| Course     | Status|
--------------------------------
1        | Art        | Nice
1        | Math       | Good
2        | Science    | Bad
```

someone can help me? how to select that table for sql?

```
     <?php $query ="Select StudentID, Course, max(StatusID) from student a, course b, process c
     where a.student = c.studentid and b.studentid = c.studentid
     group by studentid, processid";
     $result=mysql_query($query);
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

     echo $row['StudentID'];
     echo $row['Course'];
     echo $row['Status'];
```

that work but the Status is not the max status.. and i try at SQL the StatusID is max result.

}
?>

Comment: Which Table You want to select?

Comment: What is your problem/requirement/question? First post it.

Comment: Please share the sql which you have tried. You are mentioning the column name as courseID in table Process and storing value 'ART' , is it correct ?

Comment: Wait, what's actually in `Process`, the numerical ids (which makes more sense, given the column names), or the text names?  Ideally, you should have some other "sorting" column - the actual value of an id should be ignored.  Otherwise, this is a variation on a standard [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem.

Comment: Are you sure that your process table is correct? In general, you seem very confused about the difference between a key (`id`) and a value (e.g. `status`)

Comment: The `Process` table indeed doesn't seem to be correct. Could you please double-check it?

Comment: sorry, i had edit that already..and sorry if my english is poor. :D

i want select the maximum of Status, but not group by studentID and Course. I have try max(courseID) but i just get the one data.

process table i think is right already, i need one student can get same course but different status, or one student can get same status but different course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a self join to get the row with highest status id per student and per course

```
select t.*
from Process t 
join (select `StudentID`, `CourseID`,max(`Status ID`) `Status ID`
     from Process 
     group by `StudentID`, `CourseID`) t1
using(`StudentID`, `CourseID`,`Status ID`)
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a28c1/2)

Also don't use spaces in table and column name instead use `_` like for column Status ID it will be good if you represent it as status_id so you don't need backticks

Comment: For full query see updated fiddle [`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8905c/1)

Comment: hi, i also want join other tables for get some data, like "Time", "Class" and i want put WHERE, how to do that? @M Khalid Junaid

Comment: @Johendry its better if you ask another question with all the brief regarding the new tables you want to join and also provide me the link here so i can look in to it

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, i cant post another question until more 3 days

Comment: @Johendry Can you update you question with all the details with sample data too for new tables?

Comment: @Johendry your update doesn't make much sense regarding new tables also the second demo that i have provided [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8905c/1) just join your tables as other tables are joined in query like Course,Status table and run your query in php to get data

Answer (score 1):

You want to know the max status of a student per course, right? In that case here's what you need:

```
  SELECT StudentID,
         CourseID,
         MAX(StatusID)
    FROM Process
GROUP BY StudentID, CourseID;
```

Comment: its just print the max id from process that is 2 | 2 | 3

Comment: You're forgetting your alphabet - `'Good'` is "greater" than (comes after) `'Bad'`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `Join` with `Group by` should work. Try this.

```
SELECT p.studentid,
       c.courseid,
       Max(p.statusid) statusid
FROM   Status s
       JOIN Process p
         ON s.StatusID = p.StatusID
       JOIN Course c
         ON c.CourseID = p.CourseID
GROUP  BY p.studentid,
          c.courseid
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the one row for distinct studentid ,courseID and you want max of Status from it, If I am correct then there is an easy solution to this

please try

```
SELECT studentid,courseid,MAX(statusid) FROM `process`
GROUP BY studentid,courseid
```

Comment: its just print the max id from process

that is

2        | 2       | 3

Comment: I have created a `Process` table with data as mentioned by you . And now you have modified the Question where you want actualstatus (not StatusIds).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.StudentID, A.CourseID, S.Status AS StatusID  
FROM (SELECT P.StudentID, P.CourseID, MAX(S.StatusID) AS StatusID  
        FROM PROCESS P 
        INNER JOIN STATUS S ON P.StatusID = S.Status 
        GROUP BY P.StudentID, P.CourseID
      ) AS A 
INNER JOIN STATUS S ON A.StatusID = S.StatusID
```